Windows11でdolphin-env-apiを使用する
Windows11でPython-env-apiを使用しPythonのスクリプトを実行することでwiiのゲームをプレイすることは可能なのでしょうか。また、可能ならばその手順を教えていただけると幸いです。如何せん情報などが少ないものでこちらに投稿させていただきました。ご助言よろしくお願いします。

対象がこれ ENPH-479/dolphin-env-api だとして、7年前の大学の講座の記録でDebian 9 Linuxでしかテストしていない(一部はMacOSとUbuntuでも)と書かれているので、そもそも今同じ環境を用意できるのか、あるいは最新のLinux系OSと最新のDolphin Emulatorで動くのかを確かめてみてはどうでしょう？ 最新環境で動くのならWSLを使うという案も考えられるのでは？
